# tRPC (on nextjs) kill not awaited promises

Tags: next.js, prisma

I have a mutation that changes data in the extern system (for example `posts`).

From my UI I public post on `external-api`
and fetch this api for refresh posts after this mutation

I want save changes that make my system in `extenal-api`, but it is not very important, more important is to update `posts` on my site immediately after addiction newPost, without awaiting save these posts in my database

I expected that this code makes it

```
  .mutation('post.add', {
    input: z.object({ title: z.string(), text: z.string() }),
    async resolve({ input }) {
      const postId = await useExternApiForPublicThisPost(input);
      
      // save change in my database, but not await response
      prisma.posts.create({
        data: {postId, ...input}
      });
    }
  })
```

but unfortunately, after resolving this request, tRPC kill Prisma, for save data in the database need await Prisma, but it's is slow

How can return response from tRPC, but continue to execute remaining promises?

Answer (score 1):

Prisma doesn't work as I expected

```
      prisma.posts.create({
        data: {postId, ...input}
      });
```

don't start promise,   promise started only after  call  .then()

I don't want use  `await prisma.post.create()` but can use `prisma.post.create().then()` or prisma.$transaction([prisma.post.create()])

the correct version of initial code

```
  .mutation('post.add', {
    input: z.object({ title: z.string(), text: z.string() }),
    async resolve({ input }) {
      const postId = await useExternApiForPublicThisPost(input);
      
      // save change in my database, but not await response
      prisma.posts.create({
        data: {postId, ...input}
      }).then();
    }
  })
```